Using default values to columns for a table with engine=Kafka
Documentation at https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka notes:

The Kafka table engine doesn't support columns with default value. If
you need columns with default value, you can add them at materialized
view level

I've trying to use that advice, and created that structure
create or replace table test.kafka_test1_data_table (
    ts DateTime,
    dt Date DEFAULT toDate(ts),
    url String,
    path String DEFAULT path(url),
    urlPath String DEFAULT cutQueryStringAndFragment(url),
    int_value UInt32 DEFAULT 1
)
ENGINE=MergeTree
ORDER BY dt;

create or replace table test.kafka_test1_kafka_queue (
    ts DateTime,
    dt Date,
    url String,
    path String,
    urlPath String,
    int_value UInt32
)
ENGINE=Kafka
SETTINGS
    kafka_broker_list='broker:port',
    kafka_topic_list='test_kafka_topc_default_values',
    kafka_group_name='clickhouse-consumer-1',
    kafka_format='JSONEachRow',
    kafka_num_consumers=3
;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test.kafka_test1_mv TO test.kafka_test1_data_table (
    ts DateTime,
    dt Date DEFAULT toDate(ts),
    url String,
    path String DEFAULT path(url),
    urlPath String DEFAULT cutQueryStringAndFragment(url),
    int_value UInt32 DEFAULT 1
) AS SELECT * FROM test.kafka_test1_kafka_queue;

And then produced that message:
{
    "ts": "2024-07-15 11:37:00",
    "url": "https://host.com/path/to/resource.ext?query=123#fragment",
    "int_value": 0
}

After message consumed, there were no default values in target table
SELECT *
FROM test.kafka_test1_data_table

Query id: 546d75e6-1afc-4ac7-aa89-7b303795dd78

┌──────────────────ts─┬─────────dt─┬─url─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─path─┬─urlPath─┬─int_value─┐
│ 2024-07-15 11:37:00 │ 1970-01-01 │ https://host.com/path/to/resource.ext?query=123#fragment    │      │         │         0 │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────┴─────────┴───────────┘

How exactly I should use default values on materialized view level?

You need to take the dt field out from the kafka_queue table definition. Otherwise I assume it's using a default value of 1970-01-01. So like this:
create or replace table test.kafka_test1_data_table (
    ts DateTime,
    dt Date DEFAULT toDate(ts),
    url String,
    path String DEFAULT path(url),
    urlPath String DEFAULT cutQueryStringAndFragment(url),
    int_value UInt32 DEFAULT 1
)
ENGINE=MergeTree
ORDER BY dt;


create or replace table test.kafka_test1_kafka_queue (
    ts DateTime,
    url String,
    path String,
    urlPath String,
    int_value UInt32
)
ENGINE=Kafka
SETTINGS
    kafka_broker_list='localhost:8080',
    kafka_topic_list='test_kafka_topc_default_values',
    kafka_group_name='clickhouse-consumer-1',
    kafka_format='JSONEachRow',
    kafka_num_consumers=3
;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test.kafka_test1_mv TO test.kafka_test1_data_table 
AS SELECT * FROM test.kafka_test1_kafka_queue;

And if I ingest the message you sent:
SELECT *
FROM test.kafka_test1_data_table
FORMAT Vertical

Query id: c60edaa2-4a2d-4ca5-9589-d78496395779

Row 1:
──────
ts:        2024-07-15 11:37:00
dt:        2024-07-15
url:       https://host.com/path/to/resource.ext?query=123#fragment
path:
urlPath:
int_value: 0

1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.

